# How to use the infile statement on the already uploaded CSV on SAS Viya?

Tags: sas

I use the demo version of the SAS Viya. It is hosted online, I haven't downloaded anything. I have uploaded the data I want to use, but I can't seem to make it work with the "infile" statement.
The files are under the "Explorer/SAS Content/Public/datasets".
So the question is, how to use the infile statement in this situation?
(Things I have tried: right click on the uploaded files, and clicking properties. Copy and paste file location. Does not work).

```
data work.banana;
infile "/Public/datasets/banana.csv";
input 
  Y
  X1
  X2 ;
run;
```

Comment: I think you need to use FILESRVC engine.  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=p0qapul7pyz9hmn0zfoefj0c278a.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: How did you upload the file to Viya? You can load it directly into CAS. If that's the case, check the PUBLIC caslib.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use FILESRVC

documentation: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=p0qapul7pyz9hmn0zfoefj0c278a.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

CODE EXAMPLE THAT WORKED FOR MY CASE:

```
filename in FILESRVC folderpath='/Users/paulxaxaxaxa@gmail.com/dataCSV/' filename='banana.csv';

data work.Banana;
   infile in delimiter=','; 
   input Y X1 X2;
run;
```